# App crashing even though nothing besides code in Xcode with Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, uicolor, sigabrt

I have tried out many different things and looked into this a lot but I can not seem to solve this problem.

The code below compiles fine and **builds successfully** but after a couple of seconds **Xcode** opens back up with the `AppDelegate` file open with the **classic Thread 1 signal SIGABRT** with the app not working.

By the way, the app is not supposed to do anything complicated, but just changing the color of the `backgroundColor`.

Please let me know and how I could change it and make it better.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    func changeBackround() {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.randomColor()
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: Selector("changeBackground"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)   
    }    
}

extension UIColor {
    static func randomColor() -> UIColor {
        let red = CGFloat(drand48())
        let green = CGFloat(drand48())
        let blue = CGFloat(drand48())
        return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Comment: See http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug a crash. Then update your question with relevant details including the complete error message and point out the exact line of code causing the crash.

Answer (score 2):

Misspeling function name `changeBackround` ,  in the selector you put `Selector("changeBackground")`, the error is because it did not find the correspondent function to the selector.

Try this.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    func changeBackground() {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.randomColor()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: Selector("changeBackground"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

}

extension UIColor {
    static func randomColor() -> UIColor {
        let red = CGFloat(drand48())
        let green = CGFloat(drand48())
        let blue = CGFloat(drand48())
        return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```